# I trigger from uiviewcontroller to viewmodel and updates view but from uiview even fetching data with urlsession works tableview reload is not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

this is my viewmodel fetching func I run it at the beginning with id = 0

```
 func fetchLocationWithQuery(with id: String) {
        NetworkManager.shared.request(type: LocationResult.self, url: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/\(id)", method: .get) { response in
            
            switch response {
            case .success(let success):
                if success.id != nil {
                    guard let data = success.residents else {
                        return
                    }
                    self.view?.updateTableView(chracters: data)
                    //   print(data)
                }
            case .failure(let failure):
                
                print(failure)
            }
        }
    }
```

then this is update func

```
   
    func updateTableView(chracters: [String]) {
        viewModel.tableViewCharacterUrlArray = chracters
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

This works with swiping too

But i have a header uiview for tableview it triggers I can see the response but not triggering self.view.updateTable func in ViewModel

```
extension CellHeader: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let arr = viewModel.locationResponseForCollectionView
        guard let query = arr[indexPath.item].id else {
            return
        }
       // print(query)
        viewModel.fetchLocationWithQuery(with: String(query))
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not triggering"? The method isn't being called, or the .success case isn't executing, or something else? Did you try setting breakpoints?

Comment: I do api call i can see the correct response, self.view?.updateTableView(chracters: data) method works but in viewcontroller  updateTableView func is not working and updates tableview @RobC